# Python Basemap Import error: "requirement already satisfied"

Tags: macos, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

What works is

```
import mpl_toolkits
```

What not works is (Import Error basemap not found)

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

I followed the instructions here :

http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html

Downloaded the lastest basemap*.tar.gz

I run the following commands:

Inside the geos folder

```
export GEOS_DIR=~/
./configure --prefix=$GEOS_DIR
make
make install
```

Inside the basemap folder

```
python setup.py install
```

Everything runs in sudo mode and no errors. Goes outputs no python binding but not as an error so i am not sure.

It seems not to be properly installed.

Mac Os X 10.10 Yosemite
Python 2.7.6

**if i type**

pip install basemap --allow-external basemap --allow-unverified basemap

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): basemap in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

so it is there but not importable?

Comment: did you try re-installing with the `--upgrade` flag? your previous installation might incomplete

Comment: and are you sure that `GEO_DIR` should be your home directory? is that where you want it? (note, with conda this whole process is `conda install basemap` and you're done)

Comment: no i have the python shipped with mac os x and want to keep it. the problem is that mpl_toolkits path is ['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits'] but the default installation is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages how can change this. i don't care where it is as long as it works.

Comment: Using conda doesn't touch Apple's Python

Comment: yes but i got a lot of other packages that only work with the default python so i want to keep that.

Comment: That definitely doesn't preclude you from installing the conda package manager into your existing environment. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me (10.10.5).
This is the error message from port (executed as root):
"Error: Port py-matplotlib-basemap not found". It looks like Port can't found the package. Maybe port needs to be configured in some ways?

Comment: This question has already been answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import/55204759#55204759?newreg=f2c0abc758004c7a9ff9134c6fda2720 For Windows specific problem, I believe the only difference is the environmental variables. I would highly suggest using Conda if you can. If you're using Mac, the easiest way to address the problem is by `brew install geos pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip`

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was this:

```
brew install gdal
```

For completeness, I did these things too:

```
conda install basemap
```

But this should be similar to your pip install method above.

Also, for completeness, I added this line to my .bash_profile:

```
export GEOS_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.4.2/
```

You may need to edit the version number.

Then, you can run:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Comment: you can use brew instead: brew install matplotlib-basemap --with-python3

Comment: @amohr your comment is no longer valid

Comment: @gkiko looks like they removed it :(  Seems like installing it is more involved now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299352/installing-basemap-on-mac-python

Comment: I had to compile it from source

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install basemap on OS X is to use Ports.

Just type in the below command and the see the magic unfold:

```
port install  py-matplotlib-basemap
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong. Using MacPorts will install a "port" version of python.

If you started off with Anaconda python distribution, the easiest way is:

```
conda install -c anaconda basemap=1.0.7
```

Please see the page from Anaconda [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/basemap)

Answer (score 0):

The better way is upgrade matplotlib module as follows:

```
pip3 install matplotlib --upgrade
```