# Python basemap module impossible to import

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, matplotlib-basemap

I have troubles to import the basemap module of mpl_toolkits in python. Here is what I get when I run the test.py script from the module directory:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid
ImportError: No module named basemap
```

I can't get it since `sys.path` gives a list of paths where I am sure the directory "basemap" is, in the "mpl_toolkits" directory. There is no problem to `import mpl_toolkits`. Here is a thing I tried, to manually add the path, and the result:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap')
>>> import basemap
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "basemap/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import pyproj
ImportError: No module named basemap
```

I tried to uninstall an reinstall basemap from source (carefully following [these](https://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-installing-matplotlib-and-basemap/) instructions), from apt-get, from conda, but it does not change anything: I can't import basemap.

Thank you for your help

Comment: in which environment did you install the module?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I was facing this issue and I was able to solve it using anaconda

After activating my profile

```
source activate MyProfileName
conda install basemap

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# setup Lambert Conformal basemap.
# set resolution=None to skip processing of boundary datasets.
m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,projection='lcc',
            resolution=None,lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=50,lon_0=-107.)
m.bluemarble()
plt.show()
```

[image: BlueMarble format of basemap]

Answer (score 48):

I was in the same situation until a minute ago, installing it through this made the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.5.0
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: I googled and tried everything I could to get 'from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap' to actually work and your answer was the only one that was successful for me. I am using python 3.6 and I only had to run the pip install line. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: There are a few other solutions for this problem that are available in Stackoverflow but this is perhaps the only one that works on Google's Colab platform. Hence this solution is very useful.

Comment: I don't actually see why this should work any differently than running `python setup.py build` and `sudo python setup.py install` in a shallow clone of the repository. What's the magic sauce? Is it the specific version of libgeos?

Comment: This worked without the 'sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.5.0'

Comment: You sir, are the MVP. Had to change `libgeos-3.5.0` to `libgeos-3.6.2` though (but it is 3.5 years later).

Comment: DO NOT use `sudo pip`! [Source](https://pages.charlesreid1.com/dont-sudo-pip/), [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo), [source](https://dev.to/elabftw/stop-using-sudo-pip-install-52mn).

Comment: This gives me the error: `E: Unable to locate package libgeos-3.5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgeos-3.5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgeos-3.5.0'`

Answer (score 18):

I do not use Anaconda, using MacOS, and I have found this solution works for me. I guess it is straight forward, and should work with both Linux and MacOs.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53171723/2570842

```
brew install geos
pip3 install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

For Ubuntu,

```
sudo apt-get install geos
sudo pip3 install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: For RHEL/Centos7 this didn't fully work for me. What worked was:

`sudo yum -y install geos-devel;
wget https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/refs/heads/master.zip;
unzip master.zip;
cd basemap-master/packages/basemap;
python -m pip install .;`

Test command: `python -c "from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap"`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue; trying to access basemap using sys would produce that error. But this worked for me:

```
import mpl_toolkits
mpl_toolkits.__path__.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/')
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Comment: I hate it when you have a problem and people ignore it and just say "just add UNKNOWN REPOSITORY to your trusted sources and install xyz". that's not a true solution, it's a dirty workaround (and even the accepted answer, lol). I'm not sure about the cause of the problem but this one seems to tackle the problem by its root. thanks!

Comment: This seems like it should be the solution. Lesson learned - scroll down to see all answers! Just spent ~30m looking at other workarounds :(

Answer (score 11):

For me, a simple

```
pip3 install basemap
```

did the trick.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me too! (on windows environment)
A simple `pip install basecamp` followed by `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`

Comment: Appears to have worked for me on an M1 Mac. Thanks! 

I did get a warning re boundary dataset file, and instructions to download high and full resolution datasets from the basemap-data-hires package. I grabbed this here: https://pypi.org/project/basemap-data-hires/

Comment: If you've already installed `geos` and `pip install basemap` still isn't working, make sure that your `GEOS_DIR` environment variable is pointing to the right place. In my case, running the latest version of `geos` installed via Homebrew on macOS, that requires running `export GEOS_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.11.0/` (or `set -Ux GEOS_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.11.0/` if you use Fish)

Answer (score 3):

Download it from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap) and install it manually.  Make sure to download the right version(i.e. if you are Python3.6 then download ***basemap‑1.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl***)

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33020524/8730201

Answer (score 3):

`conda install -c anaconda basemap`

**OR**

Go to Anaconda Navigator, search for `basemap` and click *Apply*.

[image: Anaconda Navigator Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my Case It works

`sudo apt install python3-mpltoolkits.basemap`

Answer (score 2):

This will help you :

```
!pip install basemap
!pip install basemap-data
```

you can check [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/yusefnewton/weather-station-using-dbscan) notebook for more information:

for more examples of machine learning algorithms [please visit](https://github.com/amirdatascience):

Answer (score 1):

I followed this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43234894/3818277

Though, I can have wrongly installed mpl_toolkits (or I do not know), in my case I found out, that basemap is located in pymodules like that:

```
    mpl_toolkits.__path__.append('/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/')
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

So this worked for me on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

After a day of trying different methods, this worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked for windows.

Download wheel package from here: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap)
Navigate to download location in terminal.
Install using pip install

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get basemap working through the following steps. Note that I did a `--user` install.

1. Create shallow clone of basemap (`git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:matplotlib/basemap.git`) or extract the tarball of the current version.
2. Install the necessary prerequisite libraries (on Ubuntu, `libgeos-dev`, `libproj-dev`, `libgeos++-dev`, `proj-data`, `proj-bin`, `libgeos-c1v5`, `libgeos`, `libproj12`, I think).
3. `pip install --user pyproj matplotlib geos` (not actually sure if `geos` is necessary).

Now, here's where I had to improvise a little bit. When I install basemap using `python setup.py install`, it creates a new egg directory among my Python packages. That directory contains an `mpl_toolkits` subdirectory which duplicates a separate `mpl_toolkits` directory installed by matplotlib.

So, instead, I did

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
cp -a lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap /my/python/packages/dir/mpl_toolkits/basemap
cp lib/_geoslib.so /my/python/packages/dir
```

I am now able to run examples like `simpletest.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Couldn't import the Basemap:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

but surprisingly Pycharm saw the library which was apparently installed in this location:

```
lib/python3.8/site-packages/basemap-1.2.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/
```

So, to make it work, I just created a symbolic link in `lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/`:

```
ln -s ../basemap-1.2.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap/ basemap
```

I know it's not a clean solution, but may be sufficient in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

On Colab you might have to add the *basemap* module to *mpl_toolkits*

```
!pip install basemap
from mpl_toolkits import basemap
```

At least, I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

To install `basemap` you need to download the wheel file from this path:

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap)

for `python 3.10` this will be the file:

***basemap‑1.3.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl***

Then you have to go to the folder where the above mentioned `.whl` file is saved and run this command from there:

`pip install basemap‑1.3.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl`

---

For Mac OS please refer:

https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/releases:

Make sure you have:

```
brew install geos
brew install matplotlib
brew install numpy
brew install proj
```

Add `export GEOS_DIR="/user/local/Cellar/geos/3.10.2/"` to your .bash profile and reload it via:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git
```

then in the `basemap/packages/basemap` directory

`pip3 install`

---

For Colab there are slight variation from Akima's answer since its been a while:

```
!sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.6.2
!sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
!pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap#subdirectory=packages/basemap
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Anaconda, it has a package for basemap

> conda install basemap

(pip doesn't have the basemap package any more)

OR

If you using Ubuntu system you can try

> apt install python3-mpltoolkits.basemap

Answer (score -1):

I had trouble with that. Fortunately, I solved the problem. Firstly, I suggest you to set Anaconda up, if you don't have. Then follow steps below;

- Create a new environment in anaconda.
- Install Jupyter Notebook and launch it. If it works, turn it off.
- Change your anaconda environment in your terminal.
- Try installation commands below;
  conda install basemap
  conda install forge ...
  pip install basemap