# Jupyter Notebook | ModuleNotFoundError: No modele named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'

Tags: python

In my terminal, I ran

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

This to import tools and libraries into the code I am using. Then, this comment appears

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4256\3536619733.py in <module>
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('autoreload', '2')
      7 #importation of python tools and libraries to be used
----> 8 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
      9 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     10 from scipy.interpolate import griddata

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

I have tried to fix the problem by updating the libraries and tools, but it didn't work.

Comment: Provide more info about what actions have you done e.g. the commands you've used for updating

Comment: You may refer to this question: [python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import)