# Basemap imported BUT "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

Trying to recreate the Earth plotting from here on Mac High Sierra:
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.13-geographic-data-with-basemap.html

Installed basemap and prerequisites via pip-3.7/macports and the following:

```
sudo pip-3.7 install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

Tried reverting to matlibplot==2.2 as per older post:
[Installing basemap on Mac / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299352/installing-basemap-on-mac-python)

```py
import mpl_toolkits.basemap as Basemap
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='ortho', resolution=None, lat_0=50, lon_0=-100)
m.bluemarble(scale=0.5);
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-94e6d5b6740c> in <module>
      5 import mpl_toolkits.basemap as Basemap
      6 plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
----> 7 m = Basemap(projection='ortho', resolution=None, lat_0=50, lon_0=-100)
      8 m.bluemarble(scale=0.5);

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Not sure where to go from here now as it look like it IS importing Basemap OK, but the version or something is incorrect? Perhaps the call is wrong? I'll check that next but any pointers would be super welcome. 73s C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about importing baseman as `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`

Comment: This error is so common, that when I read this I guessed that you were committing it haha